# Change brightness on specified hours - twice a day

Tags: android, alarmmanager, brightness

I have an array of specified hours for each day, when brightness should by changed for application which is **awake 24/7**. It happens twice a day.

What I want to achieve is to find the most **economical** way of implementation that problem.

Should I use `AlarmManager` or maybe there is a better sollution?

`Activity` is always awake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to use an `AlarmManager` with `BroadcastReceiver` setting value in `SharedPreferences` and then in Activity I have a `Handler` which checks that value.

Answer (score 1):

If your app doesn't show any UI while it's awake, use the `AlarmManager`.

Comment: @pawegio why? Is it always displayed to the user? Does the device never go to sleep?

Comment: Yes... device will never go to sleep. Application will be delivered to public places.